# While loop error c++

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, while-loop

i have a while loop that throws the exception  before entering a location  or file name. here is the code:

### find.cpp

```
  cout << "enter file name or  location> " << flush;
  while (true)
  {
  string thefilename;
  getline( cin, thefilename );
  thefile.open( thefilename.c_str() );


  if (thefile) break;
  cout << "Invalid file. Please enter  file name or location> " << flush;

  }


  while(getline(thefile, temp))
        cout << temp << endl;
    thefile.clear();
    thefile.open("blabla.txt");


    cout << endl;
    thefile.close();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
             }
```

when i run this i get

```
      enter file name or location>Invalid file. Please enter  file name or location>
```

instead of

```
      enter file name or location>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need the `<< flush` on the `cout` line. `cin` and `cout` are tied, so reading from `cin` will flush `cout` unless you've turned this off.

Comment: Your formatting is confusing. The way its written, you can get unexpected results.

Comment: yes its in the same directory. the file opens properly, but it says invalid file the first time its run before  entering the file name or location

Comment: you open-file code works fine on my machine

Comment: Oh, and while I'm at it, despite the title, this code does **not** throw an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost certainly omitted the interesting bit of code: what happened before the input of the filename! Probably, it was preceded by some formatted input (i.e., using `std::cin >> value`), e.g., reading a number: formatted input stops at the first character not matching the format. For example, it stops at the newline encountered resulting from using the enter key to enter the value.

To fix the problem you should probably get rid of leading whitespace, e.g., using the `std::ws` manipulator:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, thefilename)) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to `ignore()` everything up to and including a newline character after the preceding input:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
while (std::getline(std::cin, thefilename)) {
    ...
}
```